# Combinding two ViewModels, 1 containing a single row results, the other containing multiple row results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to figure out how I would combine two of the `ViewModels` I have created (GameSectionVM and ReleaseInfoVM) and then appropriately filling it with data (which I think I know how to do). Normally I would just copy the code from one to the other but what is getting me hung up is the fact that the GameSectionVM would only contain a single row result of the DB query, while the other VM (ReleaseInfoVM) would contain 0 or more row results. I am also a bit unsure of how I would fill the VM with all the data and just need a confirmation that my code thought is right on that.

GameSectinVM:

```
public class GameSectionVM
{
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string LogoFileName { get; set; }
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
}
```

ReleaseInfoVM

```
public class ReleaseInfoVM
{
    public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseName { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public string ReleaseDateText { get; set; }
    public string DateReleased
    {
        get
        {
            return (ReleaseDate.HasValue) ? ReleaseDate.ToString() : ReleaseDateText;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I currently use to fill both VMs:

```
var model = (from s in db.Sections
            join f in db.Files
            on s.LogoFileID equals f.ID into s_f
            where s.RouteName == SectionName
            from x in s_f.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new GameSectionVM
            {
                GameTitle = s.Title,
                LogoFileName = x.FileName,
                Synopsis = s.Synopsis
            }).Single();
var ReleaseInfo = db.Releases.All(r => r.SectionID == SectionID);
```

I would imaging the code to fill the ReleaseData would stay the same when the two VMs are combined but instead of `var ReleaseInfo` it would become `model.ReleaseInfo`

EDIT: I forgot to note that each game section can have multiple releases, which is why I want to combined the two VMs so a single model passed up to the View will have the Section's Title, Logo, Synopsis, and all the Release information for each release of that game. At the database level the two tables (Section and Release) are tied together by `Release.SectionID` being a `FK` to `Section.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a parent -> child relationship between `GameSectionVM` and `ReleaseInfoVM`, then the easiest way to do this would be to add an `ICollection<ReleaseInfoVM>` to the properties of `GameSectionVM`.

```
public class GameSectionVM
{
...
public ICollection<ReleaseInfoVM> ReleaseInfos {get;set;}
}
```

code to fill the VM:

```
// this var will evaluate to GameSectionVM
var model = (from s in db.Sections
...
}).Single();

model.ReleaseInfos = (from r in db.Releases
...
// Do your query logic to populate the ReleaseInfoVM tables here
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added an `ICollection<ReleaseInfoVM>` as suggested but now the query to get the info says it can not convert from IQueryable to ICollection
`model.ReleaseInfo = (from r in db.Releases
                                             where r.SectionID == model.SectionID
                                             select new ReleaseInfoVM
                                             {}).All();`

Comment: you can either use `IQueryable` in your VM (performance concerns you may want to read up on) or use `.All().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Given that `GameSectionVM` and `ReleaseInfoVM` don't look anything like each other, I assume what you mean is to create a third ViewModel that has a single `GameSectionVM` as a property and a collection of `ReleaseInfoVM` instances as another property.

This should be fairly straightforward:

```
public class CombinedVM
{ 
    public GameSectionVM GameSection { get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ReleaseInfoVM> ReleaseInfos { get;set; }
}
```

... and assuming you have already retrieved the `GameSectionVM`and the list of `ReleaseInfoVM` instances, you could construct the model like this:

```
 var newModel = new CombinedVM() { GameSection = model, ReleaseInfos = ReleaseInfo };
```

Comment: Sorry I should have stated in the post that a Game Section would have 0 or more release information (i.e. multiple release dates/locations) So The two should be part of the same ViewModel, but since a Game Section would only have 1 Title, Logo, and Synopis but can have multiple sets of release information I am not sure how to combined the two. I added an edit to the original post making the connection between the two.